# HTML markup small table in the side

Tags: html, css

In this html, the table appears beside the span's - how can i force the spans to appear below the level of the table

```
<div>
    <table align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        <span>smthg</span>
         -
         <span>smthg</span>
         -
         <span>smthg</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables no longer have an `align` attribute. Remove `align="right"` and the spans will appear below the table.

If you want the table on the right then use css and `float: right` and add `clear: right` (clearing the float) to the following div so that it sits below the table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Some Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
table {
    float: right;
}
#following {
    clear: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>smthg</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="following">
    <div>
        <span>smthg</span>
         -
         <span>smthg</span>
         -
         <span>smthg</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you were looking for?

```
<body> 
<div>
    <div>
        <span>smthg</span>
        -
        <span>smthg</span>
        -
        <span>smthg</span>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <table align="right">
        <tr>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brandonq/7Nc3N/

Comment: "how can i force the spans to appear **below** the level of the table" -- the OP

Comment: My bad, read it wrong. Just got home from work. Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/brandonq/7Nc3N/1/